# Windows UWP desktop app published in Visual Studio 2019 missing icons

Tags: windows, visual-studio, uwp, icons

I've developed a UWP desktop app in VS 2019 and C#, and used VS to automatically generate visual assets from a source JPG image.

This works fine in Debug and Release configurations (in particular, the proper icon appears in the taskbar), but when I generate a self-signed msixbundle and use it to install the application on my laptop and run it, images are missing from several locations, including the taskbar icon and desktop shortcuts, but appear in others, such as the start menu, search results and flash screen.

I've tried playing with the settings for the automatic generator and manually generating images and updating the manifest file, but nothing seems to work. As nearly as I can figure out, the images needed for things like the taskbar icon are being generated into the Assets folder, but they are not being included in the bundle when published.

Is there a solution/workaround for this (short of getting a more competent developer)?

Edit: A blank, gray rectangle appears when icons are missing.

Comment: You could try to install the app in another machine such as desktop computer to determine if the problem is related to your laptop. Could you please share me with the detailed steps about how to automatically generate visual assets and install the application?

Comment: 1. Open a VS solution.

Comment: 2. Open a project in the Solution Explorer.
3. Double-click on Package.Appxmanifest.
4. On my most recent attempt: Click on the "Visual Assets" tag and provide all information, including source, for the Asset Generator. Next to "Assets" I selected all except "Badge Logo", the default. Next to "Scales" I selected "All Scales".
5. Click the Generate button, and all image files are added to the Assets folder under the project.

Comment: From there it is a matter of publishing the project and using the msixbundle file to install the application.

Comment: Found a work-around. Published without creating a bundle and the resulting msix file works just fine! Thanks for your help, actually describing the steps led me to reconsider using the bundle file, ignoring VS's recommendation.